# Find top 500 oldest files

Tags: linux, bash, find

How can I find top 500 oldest files?

What I've tried:

```
find /storage -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.flv" -type f | sort | head -n500
```

Comment: that'll just print 500 files, sort them alphabetically, and display the first 500. read the find man page, figure out how to print the file timestamps FIRST, so you end up with "<timestamp> <name of file>" in your output, and then tell `sort` to deal with an integer value in the first column.

Comment: What do you mean by "oldest"?  Do you have a filesystem that keeps track of the creation time of the file?  Most filesystmes do not retain that information.

Answer (score 1):

Find 500 oldest files using GNU find and GNU sort:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -a files
export LC_{TIME,NUMERIC}=C
n=0

while ((n++ < 500)) && IFS=' ' read -rd '' _ x; do
    files+=("$x")
done < <(find /storage -type f \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.flv' \) -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn)

printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Update - some explanation:

As mentioned by Jonathan in the comments, the proper way to handle this involves a lot of non-standard features which allows producing and consuming null-delimited lists so that arbitrary filenames can be handled safely.

GNU find's `-printf` produces the mtime (using the undocumented `%T@` format. My guess would be that whether or not this works depends upon your C library) followed by a space, followed by the filename with a terminating `\0`. Two additional non-standard features process the output: GNU sort's `-z` option, and the `read` builtin's `-d` option, which with an empty option argument delimits input on nulls. The overall effect is to have `sort` order the elements by the mtime produced by `find`'s `-printf` string, then read the first 500 results into an array, using `IFS` to split `read`'s input on space and discard the first element into the `_` variable, leaving only the filename.

Finally, we print out the array using the `%q` format just to display the results unambiguously with a guarantee of one file per line.

The process substitution (`<(...)` syntax) isn't completely necessary but avoids the subshell induced by the pipe in versions that lack the `lastpipe` option. That can be an advantage should you decide to make the script more complicated than merely printing out the results.

None of these features are unique to GNU. All of this can be done using e.g. [AST find(1)](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/man/man1/find.html), openbsd `sort(1)`, and either Bash, mksh, zsh, or ksh93 (`v` or greater). Unfortunately the `find` format strings are incompatible.

Comment: You should explain what you're doing. You're using Bash process substitution as well as the `-printf` extension to find and null terminated 'lines' which GNU `sort` interprets.  All very powerful, but needing some explanation since they are all GNU extensions compared with, say, the POSIX standard.  (You do get credit for saying GNU `find` and `sort` up front.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. Added a few explanation paragraphs.

Comment: wont it be easier to do? `find . -regex ".*\.\(flv\|mp4\)" -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -n 500`

Comment: @Orlo Not really. First, the long-form `-name` is just much more customary. `-regex` I see very infrequently, probably because it's so non-portable. Secondly, and possibly most importantly, `-regex` is not equivalent. `-regex` is more like `-path` in that it matches against the entire pathname, not just the filename. It is definitely not a replacement for `-name`. And aside from that, using null delimiters IS the correct way to handle serialized collections of filenames in almost any shell application. Newline delimiter is unsafe, and if you have the tools to avoid that then you should.

Answer (score 0):

The following finds the oldest 500 files with the oldest file at the top of the list:

```
find . -regex  '.*.\(mp4\|flv\)' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -drt --quoting-style=shell-always 2>/dev/null | head -n500
```

The above is a pipeline.  The first step is to find the file names which is done by find.  Any of find's options can be used to select the files of interest to you.  The second step does the sorting.  This is accomplished with `xargs` passing the file names to `ls` with sorts on time in reverse order so that the oldest files are at the top.  The last step is `head -n500` which takes just the first 500 file names.  The first of those names will be the oldest file.

If there are more than 500 files, then `head` terminates before `ls`.  If this happens, `ls` will issue a message: `terminated by signal 13`.  I redirected stderr from the xargs command to eliminate this harmless message.

The above solution assumes that all the filenames can fit on one command line in your shell.

Comment: ls method doesn't work at all. `ls: cannot access '**/*.mp4': No such file or directory` the find method doesn't sort the "oldest files" first.

Comment: `globstar` is a shopt option. in ksh93 you can set it with `set -o globstar` or `set -G`, but those don't work in bash.

Comment: @Orlo (a) Both methods produce the oldest 500 files.  If you want the oldest 500 with the oldest at the top, I can add that.  Note that the `find` method pipes its output to `ls` which does the sorting on time.  (b) The `cannot access` message that you reported simply means that there was no such file in a subdirectory.  If all your files are not spread out over subdirectories, you can omit the `**` globs.

Comment: @Orlo I revised the answer so the the oldest file is at the top.  I also eliminated the approach using `ls` alone so as to avoid the issue of setting globstar and nullglob.

Comment: Suppose `xargs` can only pass 500 files at a time to `ls`; suppose that there are 3,000 files to process.  Then this will get the first list of 500 files in reverse date order, but there could easily be older files in the output from the second and subsequent invocations of `ls`.  You have to generate the entire list of files with timestamps (maybe the `stat` command?) and then sort that entire list (use ISO 8601 date/time notation: `2014-02-09 17:03:25`, etc, as that sorts into order with a simple sort), and then take the oldest 500 files (first 500 or last 500, depending on how you sort).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I was aware of that hypothetical (which is why I included the caveat in the answer) but I have used it with as many as 50,000 file names at once without such behavior.